# javascript regular expression to test letter and number existens

Tags: javascript, html, regex

i have this regular expression in this code:

```js
function validateUser() {
   var e = /^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9]).*$/;
    else(e.test(document.getElementById("username")) == false){
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("error");   
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("ok");
    }
```

i want it to test if the string starts with a letter and contains at least 1 number 
but even if i enter a string that contains a number i still get the error msg!

Comment: Remove `+` from the second one. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Try `/^[a-z]+[0-9][0-9a-z]*$/i.test(s)` if you need to only match alphanumeric strings.

Comment: <what goes here>`else if`

Comment: Hi scofildo, I have made changes in my answer. Please check the snippet and let me know whether that solves your question or not.

Comment: Based on your  requirement "*starts with a letter and contains at least one number*", then `/^[a-z]+.*\d.*/i` will do. However it will allow almost anything in the string in addition to letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function validateUser(thatObj) {
 var patt = /^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9]).*$/;
   if(patt.test(thatObj.value) == false){
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("error");   
   }
   else{
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("ok");
   }
 }
```

```html
User Name: <input type="text" id="username" oninput="validateUser(this)"/><br>
Status: <span id="s"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z].*\d.*$/
```

Will allow any string which starts with a letter and contains at least 1 digit.

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xSblQM/1)

Comment: i still get the error message even if the entered string is correct
<script>
function validateUser() {
   var e = /^[a-zA-Z].*\d.*$/;
   if(e.test(document.getElementById("username")) == false ){
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("msg1");   
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("msg2");
}
</script>

Comment: @scofildo—then your error is elsewhere. The regular expression fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The following will test the full string based on your stated criteria:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/
```

**Explanation:**

`^`         *match start of string*

`[a-zA-Z]+` *match one or more of any letter of the alphabet*

`[0-9]+`    *match one or more of any numerical digit*

Comment: No, it won't test the *full string*, as you only have the leading anchor in the pattern.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert by any means but my understanding is the solution I provided will check the full string that is supplied to it.  Strings are not necessarily concluded by line breaks, no?

Comment: @alaric—"no", but unlikely that a username will contain a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a scope closure syntax and a conditional is corrupt.
Telltale missing closure is the error is generated on *line 20* or there abouts.

It should be

```
function validateUser() {  // <- Begin function block
   var e = /^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9]).*$/;
    // else <- if what ? 
    if(e.test(document.getElementById("username")) == false){
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("error");   
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML=("ok");
    }
} // <- function block closure
```